# Formula for $\Pr\Big((X,Y,Z,T) \textrm{ in } A \Big)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

For a univariate random variable, we have the formula 
\begin{equation}
\Pr(X \textrm{ in } A)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Pr(X \textrm{ in } A | Y=y) f_Y(y)dy,
\end{equation}
what about the case that we have several random variables, say, 
\begin{equation}
\Pr\Big((X,Y,Z,T)  \textrm{ in } A \Big).
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see in what your formula is interesting since it's just $$\int_A f_X(x)dx.$$

Nevertheless,
$$\mathbb P\{X\in A, Y\in B\}=\int_B \mathbb P\{X\in A\mid Y=y\}\mathbb P\{Y\in \,\mathrm d y\}.$$

So if $Y$ is continuous, then
$$\mathbb P\{X\in A, Y\in B\}=\int_B \mathbb P\{X\in A\mid Y=y\}f_Y(y)\,\mathrm d y.$$

Or, if $(Y_1,...,Y_n)$ is continuous, $$\mathbb P\{X_1\in A_1,...,X_m\in A_m, Y_1\in B_1,...,Y_n\in B_n\}=\int\limits_{B_1\times ...\times B_m}\mathbb P\{X_1\in A_1,...,X_m\in A_m\mid Y_1=y_1,...,Y_n=y_n\}f_{Y_1,...,Y_n}(y_1,...,y_n)\,\mathrm d y_1...\,\mathrm d y_n,$$

where $f_{Y_1,...,Y_n}$ is the join distribution.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in the question. I correct it.

Comment: @Math_Mania: then I answered to your question.